# Reading from a URL in java: when is a request actually sent?

Tags: java, url

I have an assignment for school that involves writing a simple web crawler that crawls Wikipedia. The assignment stipulates that I can't use any external libraries so I've been playing around with the java.net.URL class. Based on the [official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html) and some code given by my professor I have:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("sun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout", "500");
    System.setProperty("sun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout",    "1000");

    try {
        URL url = new URL(BASE_URL + "/wiki/Physics");
        InputStream is = url.openStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        String inputLine;
        int lineNum = 0;
        while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null && lineNum < 10) {
            System.out.println(inputLine);
            lineNum++;
        }   
        is.close();
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }   
}
```

In addition, the assignment requires that:

> Your program should not continuously send requests to wiki.  Your program
>   must wait for at least 1 second after every 10 requests

So my question is, where exactly in the above code is the "request" being sent? And how does this connection work? Is the entire webpage being loaded in one go? or is it being downloaded line by line?

I honestly don't really understand much about networking at all so apologies if I'm misunderstanding something fundamental. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
 InputStream is = url.openStream();
```

at the above line you will be sending request

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
```

at this line getting the input stream and reading.

Calling url.openStream() initiates a new TCP connection to the server that the URL resolves to. An HTTP GET request is then sent over the connection. If all goes right (i.e., 200 OK), the server sends back the HTTP response message that carries the data payload that is served up at the specified URL. You then need to read the bytes from the InputStream that the openStream() method returns in order to retrieve the data payload into your program.

Comment: So, to be clear, if I call `readline()` 10 times in the above code, is each one of those an HTTP request, or is the only request in the line with with `url.openStream()`?

Comment: readline() is a method used to read characters from input stream and put them in the string in one go.